# Is there a simpler way to implement a JSON REST service with net/http?

Tags: json, http, rest, go, httpserver

I am trying to develop a *REST* service with `net/http`.

The service receives a JSON structure containing all the input parameters. I wonder if there is an easier and shorter way to implement the following:

```
func call(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error parsing request %s\n", err)
    }
    var buf []byte
    buf = make([]byte, 256)
    var n, err = r.Body.Read(buf)
    var decoded map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(buf[:n], &decoded)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error decoding json: %s\n", err)
    }
    var uid = decoded["uid"]
    ...
}
```

As you can see it requires quite a number of lines just to get to the extraction of the first parameter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call `r.ParseForm` if the body of the request will contain a JSON structure and you don't need any URL parameters.

You don't need the buffer either; you can use:

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
```

And then:

```
error := decoder.Decode(decoded)
```

Putting it all together:

```
func call(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    values := make(map[string]interface{})

    if error := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&values); error != nil {
        panic(error)
    }

    uid := values["uid"].(int)

}
```

It would be much nicer, though, if you could formally define the structure of the input that you're expecting in a struct type:

```
type UpdateUserInformationRequest struct {
    UserId int `json:"uid"`
    // other fields...
}
```

And use an instance of this struct instead of a more general map.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive answer. I wonder: what is that `json:"uid"` specification that you set within the `UserId` field? Is that a language feature?

Comment: You're welcome. That's a struct field-tag and it's read by the `json` package when decoding. The way they are intepreted is documented here: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal